# Warning: PDO::prepare() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer

Tags: model-view-controller, methods

I get

> Warning: PDO::prepare() expects parameter 2 to be array, integer
>   given in /var/www/html/mvc_patern/libs/Model.php on line 29

Main Model.php

```
<?php
  class Model{

public $table;
public $id;
protected $_db;


public function __construct($username = "mvcpatern", $password = "mvcpatern", $host = "localhost", $dbname = "mvcpatern", $options = []){
    // $this->pdo = TRUE;
    try {
        $this->_db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
        $this->_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}

// get row

public function getRow($id){
    try {
        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare(
        "SELECT *
        FROM `{$this->table}`
        WHERE id={$id})",
        PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetch();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
}
}
?>
```

in subModel

```
    <?php
  class Article_Model extends Model {
  public $table = 'articles';
  public $message;
  public function __construct() {
   parent::__construct();
  }    
}
?>
```

Finaly a call method

```
<?php
      $message = new Article_Model();
      $message->getRow(1);
    ?>
```

What is wrong with my method  getRow? Why it asking parameter array if i defined "table" & "id"?